# How to quickly mirror a Mongo database?

Tags: mongodb

What's a quick and efficient way to transfer a large Mongo database?

I want to transfer a 10GB production Mongo 3.4 database to a staging environment for testing. I used the mongodump/mongorestore tools to test this transfer to my localhost, but it took over 8 hours and consumed a massive amount of CPU and memory, which is something I'd like to avoid in the future. The database doesn't have any indexes, so the mongodump option to exclude indexes doesn't increase performance.

My staging environment will mostly be read-only, but it will still need to write occasionally, so it can't be setup as a permanent read replica of production.

I've read about [replication sets][1], but they seem very complicated to setup and designed for permanent mirroring of a primary to two or more secondaries. I've read some posts about people hacking this to be temporary, so they can do a one-time mirroring, but I can't find any reliable documentation since this isn't the intended usage of the feature. All the guides I've read also say you need at least 3 servers, which seems unintuitive since I only have 2 (production and staging) and don't want to create a third.

Answer (score 4):

Several options exist today (2020-05-06).

**Copy Data Directory**

If you can take the system offline you can copy the data directory from one host to another then set the configuration to point to this directory and start up the new mongod.

**Mongomirror**

Mongomirror (https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/import/mongomirror/) is intended to be a tool to migrate from on-premises to Atlas, but this tool can be leveraged to copy data to another on-premises host.  Beware, this connection requires SSL configurations on source and target to transfer.

**Replicaset**

MongoDB has built-in High Availability features using a replica set model (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/deploy-replica-set/).  It is not overly complicated and works very well.  This option allows the original system to stay online while replication does its magic.  Once the replication completes reconfigure the replica set to be a single node replica set referring only to the new host and shut down the original host.  This configuration is referred to as a single-node replica set.  Having a single node replica set offers benefits over a stand-alone installation in that the replica set underpinnings (oplog) are the basis for other features such as change streams (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/changeStreams/)

**Backup and Restore**

As you mentioned you can use mongodump/mongorestore.  There is a point in time where the backup must be restored.  During this time it is expected the original system is offline and not accepting any additional writes.  This method is robust but has downtime associated with it.  You could use mongoexport/mongoimport to use a JSON file as an intermediate step but this is not recommended as BSON data types could be lost in translation.

Answer (score 1):

Per Mongo documentation, you should be able to `cp/rsync` files for creating a backup (if you are able to halt write ops temporarily on your production setup - or if you do this during a maintenance window)

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/backups/#back-up-by-copying-underlying-data-files

> Back Up with cp or rsync
>
> If your storage system does not support snapshots, you can copy the files >directly using cp, rsync, or a similar tool. Since copying multiple files is not >an atomic operation, you must stop all writes to the mongod before copying the >files. Otherwise, you will copy the files in an invalid state.
>
> Backups produced by copying the underlying data do not support point in time >recovery for replica sets and are difficult to manage for larger sharded >clusters. Additionally, these backups are larger because they include the >indexes and duplicate underlying storage padding and fragmentation. mongodump, >by contrast, creates smaller backups.

FYI - for replica sets, the third "server" is an arbiter which exists to break the tie when electing a new primary. It does not consume as many resources as the primary/secondaries. Since you are looking to creating a staging environment, i would not recommend creating a replica set that includes production *and* staging env. Your primary instance could switch over to the staging instance and clients who are meant to access production instance will end up reading/writing from staging instance.